# What is the short for "focusing on the key component of the problem?"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english

I am writing a research essay which contains something like "a policy that focuses on the key component of the problem." I am struggling to come up with a short name for this policy because I need to write it in a section title. I need something like "key-component-focusing policy," but this is still a little long. Could anyone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Does it need to include the word "policy"?

Answer (score 2):

"root cause" is often the term used

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_cause_analysis

Comment: I think the OP would like *root cause analysis* better than *root cause*.

Answer (score 2):

If something focuses on the key component of an issue then it is said to focus on the '***[crux](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crux)*** of the issue'.

> **[Crux:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crux)** the basic, central, or critical point or feature: *'the crux of the matter'; 'the crux of an argument'*.

A synonym of crux is ***[nub](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nub)***.

> **[Nub:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nub)** the essence; the core: '*the nub of a story*'.

Both definitions sourced from thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

You might call it the [***keystone***](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/keystone) policy.

> a central cohesive source of support and stability

... which would indicate without this *core, central, primary, main, critical,* etc. policy, then the other policies would have little effect and everything would fall to pieces.